# Elegant implementation of a caching system using only Google Guava that allows null values to be cached with a different expiry from non-nulls?

Tags: java, caching, guava

Here's my setup:

```
    private final LoadingCache<String, Optional<SampleInfo>> infoCache;
    private final LoadingCache<String, Optional<SampleInfo>> nullInfoCache;

        this.infoCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(CACHE_EXPIRY_HOURS, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, Optional<SampleInfo>>() {

                    @Override
                    public Optional<SampleInfo> load(final String key) throws Exception {
                        return service.api(key);
                    }
                });

        this.nullInfoCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(NULL_CACHE_EXPIRY_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, Optional<SampleInfo>>() {

                    @Override
                    public Optional<SampleInfo> load(String key) throws Exception {
                        return service.api(key);
                    }
                });
```

And, here's how I'm hoping to use the two caches in tandem:

```
           optSampleInfo = nullInfoCache.getIfPresent(sampleId);
            if (optSampleInfo == null || !optSampleInfo.isPresent()) {
                optSampleInfo = infoCache.get(sampleId);
                if (!optSampleInfo.isPresent()) {
                    nullInfoCache.put(sampleId, optSampleInfo);
                    infoCache.invalidate(sampleId);
                }
            }
```

This isn't very elegant. How do I make it better? I do not wish to use any special caching libraries. I also cannot afford to not cache nulls at all. They just need to be cached for a much shorter period.

Comment: Maybe encapsulate them both in one wrapper?

Comment: Use Guava's successor, [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) and a custom `expireAfter(expiry)` that evaluate to different durations based on the `Optional` being present / absent.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit @xtratic?